# php remove "_" from this context

Tags: php

I have file with this text

```
<Actions><action_0>extractNumbersFromString</action_0><action_1>extractNumbersFromString</action_1></Actions>
```

I would like to remove the `_number` from it.

how please?

#### Note

the file is not formatted as XML. In other words, there are no "enter" but all the text comes after each other.

Comment: Enters are not mandatory in XML, so it still *can* be valid XML. Can you specify whether you want to edit the file, or just modify output that you initially read from a file? Also, can you verify whether the file is actual XML? If it is you can use an XML parser, otherwise you cannot, so it makes all the difference.

Comment: @GolezTrol if the enters don't count so yes I have a valid xml file with xml extension and with 100% xml format, and I want to replace the file with the new file which doesn't have the `_number` in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly...

```
file_put_contents('your-file-name-here',
  preg_replace('/(attribute|action)_[0-9]+/', '$1',
    file_get_contents('your-file-name-here')
  )
);
```

Comment: because your answer seems great, I would like to tell you that I also have `attribute_number`, can you remove that please too?

Comment: I got this exception `preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: Sorry, removed it accidentally while formatting code. Now should be ok. Added `attribute` as well.